# Scrapy+Splash return 403 for any site

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen

For some reason, I have 403 for any request when using Splash. What I do wrong?

Following https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash I set up all the settings:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Started splash with docker

> sudo docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash

Spider code:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy import Selector
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class VestiaireSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vestiaire"
    base_url = "https://www.vestiairecollective.com"
    rotate_user_agent = True

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["https://www.vestiairecollective.com/men-clothing/jeans/"]
        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'args': {"wait": 0.5}})

    def parse(self, response):
        data = Selector(response)
        category_name = data.xpath('//h1[@class="campaign campaign-title clearfix"]/text()').extract_first().strip()
        self.log(category_name)
```

Then I run the spider:

> scrapy crawl test

And get back a 403 for requesting url:

> 2017-12-19 22:55:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started
>   (bot: crawlers) 2017-12-19 22:55:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO:
>   Overridden settings: {'DUPEFILTER_CLASS':
>   'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 10,
>   'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'crawlers.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES':
>   ['crawlers.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'COOKIES_ENABLED':
>   False, 'BOT_NAME': 'crawlers', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE':
>   'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'} 2017-12-19 22:55:17
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
>   ['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage', 
>   'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats'] 2017-12-19 22:55:17
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
>   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats'] 2017-12-19
>   22:55:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
>   ['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware', 
>   'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware'] 2017-12-19 22:55:17
>   [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
>   ['scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline'] 2017-12-19 22:55:17
>   [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened 2017-12-19 22:55:17
>   [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min),
>   scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) 2017-12-19 22:55:17
>   [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on
>   127.0.0.1:6023 2017-12-19 22:55:20 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) https://www.vestiairecollective.com/robots.txt> (referer:
>   None) 2017-12-19 22:55:22 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403)
>   http://localhost:8050/robots.txt> (referer: None) 2017-12-19
>   22:55:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) https://www.vestiairecollective.com/men-clothing/jeans/ via
>   http://localhost:8050/render.html> (referer: None) 2017-12-19 22:55:23
>   [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403
>   https://www.vestiairecollective.com/men-clothing/jeans/>: HTTP status
>   code is not handled or not allowed 2017-12-19 22:55:23
>   [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished) 2017-12-19
>   22:55:23 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
>   {'downloader/request_bytes': 1254,  'downloader/request_count': 3, 
>   'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2, 
>   'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1, 
>   'downloader/response_bytes': 2793,  'downloader/response_count': 3, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1, 
>   'downloader/response_status_count/403': 2,  'finish_reason':
>   'finished',  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 19, 20, 55,
>   23, 440598),  'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1, 
>   'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/403': 1,  'log_count/DEBUG':
>   4,  'log_count/INFO': 8,  'memusage/max': 53850112, 
>   'memusage/startup': 53850112,  'response_received_count': 3, 
>   'scheduler/dequeued': 2,  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2, 
>   'scheduler/enqueued': 2,  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2, 
>   'splash/render.html/request_count': 1, 
>   'splash/render.html/response_count/403': 1,  'start_time':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 19, 20, 55, 17, 372080)} 2017-12-19
>   22:55:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

Comment: Have you tried `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` in scrapy's `settings.py` ?

Comment: Also, from the splash docs: `Don’t forget, if you’re using a Docker Machine on OS X or Windows, you will need to set this to the IP address of Docker’s virtual machine, e.g.:

SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050/'
`

Comment: WIth `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False` I have the same problem

Comment: Did you try to render the page in Splash web console?

Answer (score 4):

The problem was in User-Agent. Many sites require it for access.
The easiest way to access the site and avoid a ban is to use this lib to randomize user agent.
https://github.com/cnu/scrapy-random-useragent