# Python Scrapy Splash doesn't render website, stuck at loading screen

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

I would like to render the following website with Scrapy Splash.

https://m.mobilebet.com/en/sports/football/england-premier-league/

Unfortunately, Splash always gets stuck at the loading screen:

[image: website]

I have already tried using a long waiting time (up to 60 seconds) with no results. My Splash version is 3.3.1 and obey robots.txt has been set to false.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested the URL in Splash from your web browser, to see if you get a different result or whether it simply gets stuck or is instead simply taking too long?

Comment: Yes, the screenshot above is from Splash inside the web browser. Time is not the issue, even with a 60 second wait, the site doesn't load correctly. So it does get stuck at that point. If I open the site in Chrome, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

There's not quite enough info to answer, but I've got a good guess.

You see, the major difference between Splash and your browser is the user agent string. You have one that looks like a person. Splash generally doesn't.

This kind of infinite loading is a method used by sites to mitigate repetitive load. Often when you're developing locally without a proxy you'll trip these issues. They are quite maddening to develop against because they're inconsistent.

Your requests are just getting dropped, you'll probably see a 403 after 5-10 minutes.

I think it's likely you can solve this issue with the method mentioned in this answer: [Scrapy+Splash return 403 for any site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895141/scrapysplash-return-403-for-any-site).

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it'll be possible - this website needs JS to be rendered. So you'll need to use something like `Selenium` to scrape information from it.
Also, perhaps what you are looking for is an API for that information - since scraping it from a website can be very inefficient. Try googling "sports REST API" - look for one with Python SDK.

Ok, so `Splash` is supposed to render the JS for you it seems. But I wouldn't rely on it too much - those websites constantly change and they are developed against latest browsers, your best bet is to use `Selenium` with `Chromium` driver (though using API is much more preferable).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm currently using Selenium for this, but I want to switch to Scrapy + Splash. I hope somebody who has more experience with Splash will answer.

Comment: Splash is a browser built for javascript rendering. It's more purpose-built than Selenium and a better fit for this problem.